# openpyxl BadZipFile: File is not a zip file while saving a xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

I was using openpyxl to work with xlsx files. But when I am saving the file. I am getting an error.
This is what I have tried :

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd        

myworkbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\ULE5KOR\Downloads\Target_100.xlsx')
mysheet = myworkbook['Sheet1']
with open(r'C:\Users\ULE5KOR\Documents\INTERNSHIP_FILES\WIP_master\dimensions','r+') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        line_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        for line_no in line_list:
                temp = data[line_no]
                mycell = mysheet.cell(row = 260, column = line_no + 14)    
                mycell.value = temp
myworkbook.save(filename = r'C:\Users\ULE5KOR\Downloads\Target_100.xlsx')
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-62-354064d42991>", line 13, in <module>
    myworkbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\ULE5KOR\Downloads\Target_100.xlsx')

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 311, in load_workbook
    data_only, keep_links)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 126, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 98, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1225, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1292, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Note : I tried all suggestion for this question but none of them worked for me.

Comment: use `pandas.read_excel` to open excel file

Comment: Are you abel to open the `Target_100.xlsx` in question with any other Spreadsheet program?